# How to share session between NodeJs and PHP using Redis?

Tags: php, node.js, session, redis

I want to share the server session between a `NodeJs` app and a `PHP` app using `Redis`. I took most of the code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mscdex/9507b0d8df42e0aec825).

NodeJs code:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({prefix: 'session:php:'}),
    name: 'PHPSESSID',
    secret: 'node.js'
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.nodejs = 'node.js!';
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.session, null, '  ') );

});
```

And it outputs:

```
{
    "cookie": {
        "originalMaxAge": null,
        "expires": null,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "path": "/"
    },
    "passport": {},
    "nodejs": "node.js!"
}
```

PHP code (I use [redis-session-php](https://github.com/TheDeveloper/redis-session-php) and [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)) :

```
require('redis-session-php/redis-session.php');
RedisSession::start();

$_SESSION['php'] = 'php';

if (!isset($_SESSION["cookie"])) {
    $_SESSION["cookie"] = array();
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

And it outputs:

```
array(2) {
    ["php"] => string(3) "php"
    ["cookie"] => array(0) { }
}
```

**The problem:** 
I would expect both sessions to look the same, but they don't ( the app is run on the same domain ). Setting the values with `set()` from `Predis\Client` works (but the values won't be on the session variable). I found [this code](https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/php-and-node-js-session-share-redi/) that I think would work, using `set()` and `get()`, but I feel that it would overcomplicate the code.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: something seems fishy with the the php redis module. I would expect to see some more configuration options for connecting to redis. can you show us the config for the PHP Redis (mainly what you are passing into the constructor

Comment: I am not passing it anything, by default if no arguments are passed it assumes assumes `127.0.0.1` and `6379` as the default host and port with a connection timeout of 5 seconds.

Comment: Wll in your node.js you are passing a secret key... i dont see the option in your code for php. could be that it isnt connecting to the same redis store?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm the author of the gist. The code worked until `express-session` started forcing signed cookies and started implementing them in a different way.

I have updated the gist to work with the latest version of `express-session`. A copy of the gist follows for convenience:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (~req.url.indexOf('favicon'))
    return res.send(404);
  next();
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    // this is the default prefix used by redis-session-php
    prefix: 'session:php:'
  }),
  // use the default PHP session cookie name
  name: 'PHPSESSID',
  secret: 'node.js rules',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.nodejs = 'Hello from node.js!';
  res.send('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(req.session, null, '    ') + '</pre>');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

app.php:

```php
<?php
// this must match the express-session `secret` in your Express app
define('EXPRESS_SECRET', 'node.js rules');

// ==== BEGIN express-session COMPATIBILITY ====
// this id mutator function helps ensure we look up
// the session using the right id
define('REDIS_SESSION_ID_MUTATOR', 'express_mutator');
function express_mutator($id) {
  if (substr($id, 0, 2) === "s:")
    $id = substr($id, 2);
  $dot_pos = strpos($id, ".");
  if ($dot_pos !== false) {
    $hmac_in = substr($id, $dot_pos + 1);
    $id = substr($id, 0, $dot_pos);
  }
  return $id;
}
// check for existing express-session cookie ...
$sess_name = session_name();
if (isset($_COOKIE[$sess_name])) {
  // here we have to manipulate the cookie data in order for
  // the lookup in redis to work correctly

  // since express-session forces signed cookies now, we have
  // to deal with that here ...
  if (substr($_COOKIE[$sess_name], 0, 2) === "s:")
    $_COOKIE[$sess_name] = substr($_COOKIE[$sess_name], 2);
  $dot_pos = strpos($_COOKIE[$sess_name], ".");
  if ($dot_pos !== false) {
    $hmac_in = substr($_COOKIE[$sess_name], $dot_pos + 1);
    $_COOKIE[$sess_name] = substr($_COOKIE[$sess_name], 0, $dot_pos);

    // https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature/blob/0aa4ec2fffa29753efe7661ef9fe7f8e5f0f4843/index.js#L20-L23
    $hmac_calc = str_replace("=", "", base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $_COOKIE[$sess_name], EXPRESS_SECRET, true)));
    if ($hmac_calc !== $hmac_in) {
      // the cookie data has been tampered with, you can decide
      // how you want to handle this. for this example we will
      // just ignore the cookie and generate a new session ...
      unset($_COOKIE[$sess_name]);
    }
  }
} else {
  // let PHP generate us a new id
  session_regenerate_id();
  $sess_id = session_id();
  $hmac = str_replace("=", "", base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sess_id, EXPRESS_SECRET, true)));
  // format it according to the express-session signed cookie format
  session_id("s:$sess_id.$hmac");
}
// ==== END express-session COMPATIBILITY ====



require('redis-session-php/redis-session.php');
RedisSession::start();

$_SESSION["php"] = "Hello from PHP";
if (!isset($_SESSION["cookie"]))
  $_SESSION["cookie"] = array();

echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($_SESSION, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: This row `$_COOKIE[$sess_name] = substr($_COOKIE[$sess_name], 0, $dot_pos);` won't make the session cookie to equal `""` ?

Comment: No. `express-session`'s cookie format is `s:<32-byte id>.<32-byte id hmac>`. So all that line is doing is setting the session cookie value to just the 32-byte id part. The code could probably be simplified a little bit since I included the `express_mutator` function, but the hmac value should still be verified.

Comment: But if I switch between PHP and NodeJs, everytime a new session id will be generated, because one of them is setting the cookie as `s:<32-byte id>.<32-byte id hmac>` and the other as `<32-byte id>`, right? How can I fix this, using 2 separate cookies?

Comment: No, there should only be one session cookie. I have tested the code personally, having each side create the session and the other side read the session. Both scenarios work just fine. `s:<32-byte id>.<32-byte id hmac>` is always set as the session cookie value in both PHP and node. `<32-byte id>` is what is stored as the key in redis.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I can't seem to get this working though. I can see the session data from each individual app, but they don't cross over. Shouldn't I be able to see the PHP session data in node and vice versa? What am I missing?

Comment: @mscdex When I use this code the key in redis just says session:php: without any id.  If I use just the bottom part I get an Id, but it's not compatible with Node, when I run my script in node it creates a new session.  I think something is wrong with your express mutator, please help.