# Node Express PHP share session over redis

Tags: php, node.js, session, express, redis

I tried implementing the solution here: [How to share session between NodeJs and PHP using Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966754/how-to-share-session-between-nodejs-and-php-using-redis)

It works great if I create a session in Node and then load my PHP page.  The sessions combine.  I need to know how to create the session in PHP and then have it combine when I visit my node site.  Both of my sites are on the same domain 100%.

In this snippet I added the $echo $sess_id line and it comes out as "" (I feel this is the crux of the problem).  If I do session_id('temp'); the redis key becomes session:php:temp but obviously it needs to be something that nodeJS understand.  I'm also definitely using the same secret key on node / php.

```
    } else {
      // let PHP generate us a new id
      session_regenerate_id();
      $sess_id = session_id();
      echo $sess_id;
      $hmac = str_replace("=", "", base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sess_id, EXPRESS_SECRET, true)));
      // format it according to the express-session signed cookie format
      session_id("s:$sess_id.$hmac");
    }
```

Because of that when I did redis-cli keys * I get a key called session:php:    with no session id.  if I do redis-cli GET session:php: I get

```
"{\"php\":\"Hello from PHP\",\"cookie\":[]}"
```

I know PHP is talking to redis, it's just not saving a real session with a session id.

I've been at this for days, any help would be GREATLY appreciated, and I'd be happy to answer any questions.

It's also worth nothing I get no errors and the following lines

```
echo json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($_SESSION, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

output

```
[

]{
    "php": "Hello from PHP",
    "cookie": [

    ]
}
```

If I start session in node those lines output the full cookie / session information from node with the php hello from php added (combined perfectly).

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` prior to `session_regenerate_id()`?

Comment: @VolkerK  Not that I am aware of.  
Within the function require('redis-session-php/redis-session.php');
RedisSession::start(); it calls session_start();  But that is executed well after the session_regenerate_id() line.

Comment: The session handling (for the current php pinstance) must be started before you can use session_id() et al. The function name `session_start()` might be a bit confusing; it doesn't "create" a new session but starts the session handling mechanism for this php instance, i.e. look up the session id (from cookies, GET/POST paraemters, ....), load existing data etc....

Comment: @VolkerK Interesting, but if I remove that line, it does create a redis session with an id, but when I go to my node app it creates a brand new session (I think because node creates a much longer session ID and doesn't recognize it as the same person).  Any suggestions?

Comment: No idea; just the basic stuff: Your error_reporting level is high enough (E_ALL|E_STRICT)? You have an eye on the [error_log](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) file? You have tested that you see parse errors, warnings and notices in that file? Is there something related to the cookie headers in that log file?